# Capture game window using wm_paint

Tags: c++

I'm trying to capture a game window using `SendMessage` with `wm_paint` and `wm_printclient`.

I already did it successfully using `PrintWindow` but the game can change between graphic engines and for some of them I get a white rectangle. I was hoping using `SendMessage` would not have this problem.

The problem is I'm getting a black rectangle as result of `SendMessage`, for any graphic engine and even for any program/window.

```
void capture::captureProgramScreen(HWND hwnd, tImage* res)
{
    RECT rc;

    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);

    //create
    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
    HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
    res->width = rc.right - rc.left - 17;
    res->height = rc.bottom - rc.top - 39;

    res->absoluteTop = rc.top;
    res->absoluteLeft = rc.left;

    SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);




    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_PRINTCLIENT, (int)hdc, PRF_CHILDREN | PRF_CLIENT | PRF_ERASEBKGND | PRF_NONCLIENT | PRF_OWNED);


    BITMAPINFO MyBMInfo = { 0 };
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader);


    if (0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, 0, 0, NULL, &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    {
        res->error = true;
        res->errorcode = 2;
        return;
    }


    res->v = std::vector<BYTE>(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);


    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = abs(MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);

    if (0 == GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, 0, MyBMInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight, &(res->v[0]), &MyBMInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS))
    {
        res->error = true;
        res->errorcode = 3;
        res->width = 0;
        res->height = 0;
        res->v.clear();
        return;
    }


    //4 Bytes per pixel order (B G R A) from [left to right] [bottom to top]



    return;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sending the message across processes? Also, what game engines cause the white rectangle? Could it be an engine that uses DirectX or OpenGL? Those bypass GDI and render directly on the screen, so it will be difficult to capture them.

Comment: Exactly OpenGL and DX. That's what I was thinking, I thought with `SendMessage` I wouldn't have that problem since is the game who writes in my hdc. Yes, this code is runing in a difrent process than the game itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a few possible issues:

1. Not all programs/windows implement `WM_PRINTCLIENT`.  Many games don't even implement WM_PAINT, as they draw continuously at their desired frame rate rather than in response to a need to update themselves.  Many games use newer graphics APIs that don't really draw to a Device Context.
2. I'm not sure why you have two calls to GetDIBits.  The first one happens before you initialize all the fields of the BITMAPINFO, so that one will fail.  It's still not completely filled out by the time you make the second call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didnt make that code but I only need to get a raw array of pixels from the image, and  I think it does two `GetDIBITS` to get the header size in the first one and then ge tonly the raw rgba pixels in the second one. I don't know if it's the correct way to do it but it works